# Density matrices vs Pauli matrices

Tags: spinors, density-operator

Studying quantum mechanics, I have suddenly come to the conclusion that Pauli matrices are essentially density matrices for spin systems. Does it make any sense or I have missed something?

Comment: They can occur as specific density matrices for a spin-1/2 system. What's your question about that?

Comment: Dear @ACuriousMind, none of the Pauli matrices can ever occur as a density matrix of any system, see my answer. ;-)

Comment: @LubošMotl: Ooops. I completely misremembered the condition to be a  density matrix. Sorry, that was a stupid comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition, density matrices are positive semi-definite matrices with trace one. Pauli matrices are neither positive semi-definite nor do they have trace one (they have zero trace). Therefore, they cannot in any way be density matrices for states of spin systems.

Of course, there is a connection to density matrices in the following way: The Pauli matrices, together with the identity matrix span the space of Hermitian operators in $\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}$, of which the density matrices are a compact subset. Therefore, any density matrix in $\mathbb{c}^{2\times 2}$ (e.g. spin 1/2 system) can be decomposed into a linear combination of Pauli matrices + the identity.

Answer (score 7):

Pauli matrices are the particular 3 Hermitian matrices with the 3 times 4 matrix entries or, more generally, three matrices obeying
$$\sigma_a \sigma_b = i\epsilon_{abc} \sigma_c + 2\delta_{ab} {\bf 1} $$
Like density matrices for a 2-state system, they are $2\times 2$ matrices. But they cannot be density matrices themselves because

1. their trace is zero while the trace of a density matrix must be one
2. they're not positively semidefinite (Pauli matrices have eigenvalues $\pm 1$) while density matrices have to be

However, the Pauli matrices, along with the unit matrix, may be used as the basis of the space of all $2\times 2$ matrices. If the coefficients are real, they are a basis of all Hermitian $2\times 2$ matrices. However, for the combination of Pauli matrices and the unit matrix to be a density matrix, the coefficient in front of the unit matrix must be $1/2$, the dominant one, while the (Pythagorean) coefficient in front of the 3 real Pauli matrices has to be smaller. This is needed for the positive semidefiniteness.